# Are these both right? "Shout her name out loud!" and "Shout out loud her name!"

Tags: grammaticality

Are both expressions acceptable?
Or is the latter(the second one) grammatically wrong or really awkward?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/49545/9368 and many others here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shout her name out loud

(the first one) is much better.

> Shout out loud her name

(the second one) does indeed read awkwardly. I hesitate to call anything "wrong" when it comes to English.